# magento-Upload category getting automatically block color background?

Tags: magento-1.9, categories

Magento uploading category thumbnail image its getting automatically block color background.Please check below image link
[Image Link](http://prntscr.com/fhs9yj)
[image]actually uploaded image don't have the background color.but its coming when i am upload to category its shown black background automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually in

> lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

and is due to the use of imagefill and not imagefillrectangle.

To fix the problem, first create the file

> /app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

and copy the contents of `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php` into it.

Next, open this file and find the line that says:

> $this->_fillBackgroundColor($newImage);

And replace with:

> $this->_fillBackgroundColor($newImage, $frameWidth, $frameHeight);

Next, find the line that says:

> if (!imagefill($imageResourceTo, 0, 0, $color)) {

And replace with:

> if (!imagefilledrectangle($imageResourceTo, 0, 0, $w, $h, $color)) {

After you go into the Magento Admin, goto Cache Management and flush all Magento Image cache.

Please try this and let me know in case of any query.

Comment: Please let me know if this solution helps you and also let me know if you need any other help as well.

Comment: thanks for  ur reply,but above solution is not working again its showing black color background for category uploading images in admin side

Comment: can you please tell me your magento version?